# How to understand "when to do it" in grammar

Tags: grammar, phrases

I am confusing of the sentence

```
I don't know when to do it.
```

I have opinion of it but I don't know it is right.
I think 'I' is subject, 'don't know' is verb, 'when' is object and 'to do it' is adverb phrase. is it right?
someone said it can be idiomatic expression.... and someone said

```
when to do it
```

is noun phrase which roles object....
What is the answer...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I: a subject
>
> don't: a contraction of "do (an auxiliary verb) not (an adverb to form
>   the negative)" whose function is negate the sentence (form the
>   negative)
>
> know: a main verb
>
> when (an interrogative adverb) to do (to-infinitive) it (a pronoun): an object of the transitive verb "know".

"When to do it" is a [**wh-clause**](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/clause-phrase-and-sentence/verb-patterns/wh-clauses) which is short for "when I should do it". I would not call it a [**noun phrase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_phrase) which has a different definition as the link indicates.

As the subject of the sentence "I" is the same subject of the "when clause (when I should do it)", "when I should do it" could be shortened to "when to do it".

You can visit the above link and read more about how the "wh-clause" works.

Comment: Thank you for your answering. I have a question. You said "when I should do it" has same subject with main sentence. so i can change it "when to do it". I think It is same with "when for me to do it" and I can summarize 'for me' right?

Comment: "When for me to do it" is redundant. Everybody can know the subject of "to do" is the same subject as the main clause and there is no need to place "for me" in the "wh-clause". A side note: Please accept an answer by clicking on the tick on the left side if you find it helpful for your previous questions. It would be nice of you.

Comment: @EricHa Oh, I was not asking you to accept this answer. It would be always better if you wait for a day or two because other users might write up a better answer. Thank you for accepting this answer and you can always change the accepted answer when there is a more helpful answer than mine in the future. Good luck. :-)

Comment: haha... I am not good at english so I cant understand all but Your answer is so helpful for me. I am thankful for your effort haha.

Answer (score 0):

I: subject

Don't: negative auxillary

Know: the main verb

When to do it: (shortent form of indirect question 'when I should do it') noun clause as the object of main verb

This is called a noun clause because it is used as the object of the sentence; i.e. , as a noun can be the subject or object of a sentence, clauses which are used as subject or object of a sentence are called noun clause.